# Web Scraping using python (Multiple class )

Tags: web-scraping

Note:- No prior experience in coding or scraping still learning......!

I am new to coding I am trying to scrape the website but it has two/multiple classes how can i extract data from multiple classes in a website please help me?

Used example code,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "-------"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,'html.parser')

oilprices = soup.find('table', class\_="oilprices__table").find_all('tr', class\_ = ("stripe show_graph update_on_load") #its workin when i use sone class
```

But i dont know how can i use multiple class and extract data
Tried methods,

```
oilprices = soup.find('table', class\_="oilprices__table").find_all('tr', class\_ = ("stripe     show_graph update_on_load"), ("stripe show_graph")
oilprices = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'stripe show_graph update_on_load'},{'stripe show_graph'})
```

Please help me with your valuable suggestions

Error in code

But i dont know how can i use multiple class and extract data
Tried methods,
oilprices = soup.find('table',

```
class\_="oilprices__table").find_all('tr', class\_ = ("stripe show_graph update_on_load"), ("stripe show_graph")
oilpricesr = soup.find_all('tr',{'class':'stripe show_graph update_on_load'},{'stripe show_graph'})
```

Please help me with your valuable suggestions

Comment: you'll need to provide more information here. Whats the url? What are you trying to scrape?